# How to expose APIs that provide dynamic data but accessible on compile time?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, design-patterns, enums

**How to expose API in between two dependent modules for compile time usage?**

While working in an iOS/Swift application, an **SDK A** exposed supported feature list API which provides collection of supported feature names (string array) to 3rd party **application B**. Now inside application B, developers require to use the supported features while writing code which has a potentiality of typo issue (developer cannot get to know the array value in compile time, only from SDK documentation though). **SDK A** cannot provide any **enum** API because they dynamically populate the supported feature list.

In such situation, how to expose API so that **application B** will be able to get the feature names in compile time? Application B team want something similar to enum so that there will not be any potentiality of typo bug. On the other hand SDK A cannot provide it as **enum** because the list is created dynamically.

### Example

Let's say the SDK called `WearableSDK` provides an API which is called at after initialization,

```swift
func supportedWearableModel() -> [String]
```

Now the application which uses the `WearableSDK` requires to pass model name while communicating with other APIs i.e.

```
sdk.connectWith(String)
```

We see when developers call the connectWith function there are chances the wrong model name is passed. But if WearableSDK were designed like an enum then developers would not worry about this type errors. For example,

```swift
func supportedWearableModel() -> [ModelEnum]
sdk.connectWith(ModelEnum)
```

But unfortunately this is not possible to make it enum because the supported model names array are generated dynamically and not always fixed.

**Note** that the total set of supported models are fixed.

How to deal with this situation?

Comment: Please provide an example, this abstraction is hard to be imagined.

Comment: @Olha I have added and example. Please let me know if the question is clear or not.

Comment: Yes, the example is very clear. Maybe you should make the question's title simpler to get more attention, but as this question is bountied, the attention shouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: Does your `WearableSDK` use some external REST API to get those strings? Or are the "strings generation" logic is built into the SDK, so that it can be changed only by recompiling the `WearableSDK` project?

Comment: It can be changed only by recompiling, no REST API. @Olha

Comment: "On the other hand SDK A cannot provide it as enum because the list is created dynamically." an array of enum can be created dynamically.

Comment: @blld could you please answer with example?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan see my Answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you looking for is to prevent creating pre-defined supported features dynamically. So all that you need is provide tokens that client can't create in unsafe way (like with String case). You can make something like this:

```
// SDK part
public protocol Feature : CustomStringConvertible {}
public extension Feature where Self : RawRepresentable, RawValue : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return rawValue.description
    }
}

public struct AnyFeature {
    public let feature : Feature
    internal init<X>(_ base: X) where X : Feature {
        self.feature = base
    }
}

public final class SDKFacade {
    
    public func supportedWearableModel() -> [AnyFeature] {
        return []
    }
    
    public func connectWith(_ feature: AnyFeature) {
        // no need to check
    }
    
    // In case that client wants to create Feature dynamically to pass it in method above
    
    public func createFeature<X>(from draft: X) throws -> AnyFeature where X : Feature {
        guard isAccessible(draft) else {
            throw FeatureNotSupported()
        }
        return AnyFeature(draft)
    }
    
    private func isAccessible(_ draft: Feature) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
}

extension SDKFacade {
    struct FeatureNotSupported : Swift.Error {}
}
```

And client side will looks like this:

```
// Client part

let facade = SDKFacade()
let models = facade.supportedWearableModel()
facade.connectWith(models[0])
```

Here client simply can't create AnyFeature due visibility level of constructor. This solution can be enhanced in future via abstractions and associate types with type erasure on Feature protocol that provide some type-binded functionality over SDK.

Comment: If i put facade.connectWith(customValue) instead of (models[0]) would it give any compile error? If not then the main purpose is not yet served.

Comment: Yes you will get compile error because you can't create customValue

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your API looks like this:

```
protocol WearableAPIManager {
    func supportedWearableModel() -> [String]
    func connectWith(_ modelID: String) 
}
```

We can consider such variants:

### Working with strings

You can explicitly specify an interface to check parameters validness:

```
protocol WearableAPIManager_2 {
    func supportedWearableModel() -> [String]
    func connectWith(_ modelID: String) -> Bool // return false if model not supported
    func isModelSupported(_ modelID: String) -> Bool // say if model is supported   
}
```

Now if a developer will pass a wrong id, they can handle it somehow.

### Working with enums

#### There's a predefined set of strings for a given domain.

Let's imagine an enum for iPhone devices with some amount of ROM memory.
It can look like this

```
enum IphoneModelEnum {
    case XR_rom16,
    case XR_rom32,
    case XR_rom64,
    case XR_rom128,
    ...
    case XSMax_rom16,
    case XSMax_rom32,
    ...
}
```

There're a lot of names in this enum, but the set is *finite*.

#### There's not predefined set of strings for a given domain, there's only a "generation function".

I guess it's not possible to use only enums in such case.

E.g. in the example with iPhones, let's say an amount of ROM for any manufactured device can infinite positive integer value.

So there can be names like `XR_rom16`, `XR_rom42`, `XR_rom12432453425`. But the names like `XR_a1` are not valid, because `a1` is not a number.

For this, you can add this `generation function` to the API, so the developers who use this API can the same access to the generation logic.

The API then can look like this:

```
enum IphoneModelEnum: CustomStringConvertible {
    case iphone8,
    case iphone8plus,
    case iphoneXR,
    case iphoneXSMax
    case iphone11

    var description : String { 
    switch self {
    case .iphone8: return "8"
    case .iphone8plus: return "i8Plus"
    case .iphoneXR: return "XR"
    }
  }
}

protocol WearableAPIManager_3 {
    func supportedWearableModel() -> [String]
    func connectWith(_ fullID: String) -> Bool // return false if model not supported
    func isModelSupported(_ fullID: String) -> Bool // say if model is supported    

    func generateFullID(_ name: ModelNameEnum, rom: Int) -> String
}

// implementation
extension WearableAPIManager_3 {
    func generateFullID(_ name: ModelNameEnum, rom: Int) -> String {
        return name.description + "_" + String(rom)
    }   
}
```

Now, you can "generate" your available strings using `generateFullID` function. And the users of your API can also use `generateFullID` function. They also can use `isModelSupported` function to have more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand SDK A cannot provide it as enum because the list is created dynamically.

An array of enum can be created dynamically:

```swift
// Exposed by SDK (All possible models)

enum Model: String {
case model1
case model2
case model3
}

// Inside the SDK

func supportedWearableModel() -> [Model]
{
    var supported: [Model] = []
    // generate dynamically at runtime
    supported += [.model1]
    supported += [.model3]
    return supported
}

// Application

func connect(model: Model)
{
    print(model)
}

let supported = supportedWearableModel()
connect(model: supported[1]) // prints "model3"
```